# Closed subspace of a metric space in which distance between any two points is at most $1$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$X$  be  a metric  space  and  $Y$  be  a  closed  subspace of  $X$  such  that  distance  between  any  two  points  is  at most $1$.  Then

$1$. $Y$  is  compact

$2$. Any continuous  function  from  $Y$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb R$  is  bounded

$3$. $Y$  is  not  an  open  subset  of $X$

$4$. None  of  the  above

If  I  take $X$  as  the  space  $\mathbb R$  under  the  metric  $d_{1}$=$min\{1,d\}$  where  $d$  is  the  euclidean  metric  and  $Y$  is  the  subspace $\mathbb Z$ . Then option $1$. is  wrong.

If  I  take  $\mathbb R$  under  discrete  metric as  $X$  and  $Y$  as  $\mathbb Z$  again  then option $3$  is  also  false.

I  am  not  sure  about  the  other  two  options. And  also  please  point  out  if  these  two are  not  done correctly.

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: What is $R$? Just a generic other topological space? Or do you mean the real numbers, $\mathbb R$? (The command for that is \mathbb R

Comment: $R$  is  the  set  of  real  numbers  and  $Z$  is  the  set  of  all  integers. Thanks  for  the  code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean $\mathbb R$ for 2,  then that's false as well.   Let $X=Y=\mathbb R$  under the discrete metric,  then all functions are continuous, but certainly not bounded (For example, the identity function).  Pretty much the discrete metric kills all of these.  For instance, take $X=Y=\mathbb R$ under the discrete metric, and that's not compact (As the cover of all singleton sets has no finite subcover).  So it's none of the above.

As a side comment, when looking for counterexamples, always try the discrete metric first!

Comment: We  must  consider  that  the  $\mathbb R$  that  $Y$  gets  mapped  to  is  under  euclidean  metric ,  at  least  not  under  discrete  metric  for  that  will  make  the  function  bounded.  Right? @Alan

Comment: Ahh, right.   Yes, the ranged set is the euclidean metric, or taxicab metric, or any unbounded metric